# Inputfield over a Video

Tags: html, css

I have an input field I want to put over a video.

I thought this was easy but sadly it isn't.

The problem is I want the videos to be drag & dropable later and I cannot use position absolute because of that.

The inputfield is currently at the right of the video.

I've used div to be able to layer the videos & inputs, that works fine with position absolute but I need something that tells the input box (the div) to just show -33px from its current position on the x axis.

I can't find anything to do this.

```
<style type="text/css">
img (z-index:1;)
input {width:33px; height:13px; position:absolute:left:50px;}

#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#div2 {
    position: relative;
    left: -33px;
    z-index: 2;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see how you do this.

Comment: position: relative should work but it somehow dosnt.

Comment: please also post the html code where the two divs are.

Comment: I'm so stupid I tried it before but I used () not {} now it works and is really simple:

 img {z-index:1;}
 input {z-index:2; width:33px; height:13px; margin-left: -38px;}

The margin-left: -38px; does the trick. x_X